Is it possible to set up the Blackbaud SKY API using Google Colab? and how?
I need to pull Advanced Lists from Blackbaud into Google Colab for analysis. I found a client to facilitate this but I think the documentation is for a local set up of Python and not for Google Colab. I've been using ChatGPT to help and I've made some progress, but getting an error ultimately.
Here is what I have for setup:

A .env file with the BB_API_Key which is pulled from the Blackbaud API subscription page
A example_sky_credentials.json file which contains my client id, client secret, and redirect_uri as "http://www.locahost:8080/"

This is the code I have:
!pip install --upgrade sky-api-python-client

!pip install python-dotenv

from authlib.integrations.requests_client import OAuth2Session

client_id = 'CLIENT_ID_TYPED_OUT'
client_secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET_TYPED_OUT'
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080/'  # You still need a proper redirect URI even if you won't use it directly in Colab.
authorization_base_url = 'https://oauth2.sky.blackbaud.com/authorization'
token_url = 'https://oauth2.sky.blackbaud.com/token'

oauth = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
authorization_url, state = oauth.create_authorization_url(authorization_base_url)

print("Visit this URL to authorize:", authorization_url)


import requests

token_url = 'https://oauth2.sky.blackbaud.com/token'
data = {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'code': 'COPY_PASTE_FROM_ADDRESS_BAR',
    'state': 'COPY_PASTE_FROM_ADDRESS_BAR',
    'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8080/',
    'client_id': 'CLIENT_ID_TYPED_OUT',
    'client_secret': 'CLIENT_SECRET_TYPED_OUT
}

response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
tokens = response.json()
print(tokens)


from sky import Sky
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

# Loading BB_API_Key from .env file
load_dotenv()


client = Sky(
    api_key=os.getenv('BB_API_Key'),
    file_path='example_sky_credentials.json',
    token_path=".sky-token"
  )




This all seems to work fairly well. Then when I try to do something with the api, for example:
response = client.getAdvancedList(list_id='123456')

I either get a spinning wheel in colab where the command just doesn't complete, or I get an error:
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
So, I'm first wondering if this will be possible in Colab at all - I don't really understand it, but ChatGPT is saying that because I'm in Colab it's like I don't have a host of my own. Second, if this is possible, am I doing it right and how do I fix this error?
Thanks!
